# Javascript - what is the difference between Promise.all vs just iterating when doing async operation inside?

Tags: javascript

I dont see the point in using Promise.all if I am just return one promise inside my iteration and saw somewhere that its wrong and I should use Promise.all. Is that wrong?

```
await Promise.all(users.map(async (user) => {
      await SomeModal.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id}, {
           $push: {messages: 'hello'+user.name}
      })
}));
```

```
await users.map(async (user) => {
      await SomeModal.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id}, {
           $push: {messages: 'hello'+user.name}
      })
});
```

Comment: `users.map` returns an array, not a promise, so `await users.map` is not going to do much awaiting...

Comment: You get the value after `Promise.all` - `const value = Promise.all([])`

Comment: ok yes the await is pointless before users.map. but why do I need a promise to be returned instead of array - i have users and im just iterating and then inside awaiting promise for this: SomeModal.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id}

Comment: If you have any code after map it will be executed before your loop in this configuration

Comment: and if i dont have any code after? can I then just use the second code (without the await before users)?

Comment: I would use `forEach` to make it clear that you don't need the results

Comment: You are not handling errors now as well, any `try..catch` will do nothing if you don't properly await

Comment: @juliascoding Why do you use `await` at all if you have nothing that is waiting for the results (or errors) of the code?